# Inputting a big number of tables into LaTeX

Tags: tables, input

I am working on the project in `LaTex` that requires me to input a large number of tables produced in `R` via `xtable` packages. Let's say I have already output a large number of tables (about 150 of them). Let's call them `table-1.tex, table-2.tex, ...table-150.tex`  I have also produced a `tex` file, which include all of these tables, so in this file, it contains basically 150 lines of, `\input{table-i.tex}`, where `i` is 1 to 150. I call this file `all-table.tex`. So when I tried to input `all-table.tex` (by using `\input{all-table.tex}`. I get an error in the below pictures. But if I try to include a fewer total number of tables (about 40-50 maximum), I can still input all of them. I wonder anyone have experience with this?

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  There is a [`morefloats` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/morefloats) that can help with dealing with many floating environments (e.g. tables).  But a simple remedy without an extra package is often to just insert `\clearpage` periodically after a certain number of tables, so I would try that first.

Comment: @AndrewSwann morefloats can't help here I think (and doesn't do much in current latex releases anyway as there isn't really a limit on float numbers any more) the error here is different, it is not that latex can't allocate a float box, it's that it has given up trying to re-insert them. (`\clearpage` will definitely fix this though.)

Comment: what options have you used on `\begin{table}[???]`

Comment: @AndrewSwann thank you!, \clearpage works

Comment: @David Carlisle, it is a bit counter-intuitive, but all of my tables are using  \begin{table}[ht].

Comment: not having [p] makes this more likely but isn't a complete fix. A fix that wouldn't require you to guess where to make a page break would be to use `[H]` from the float package.

Comment: note that `[ht]` prevents `p` so prevents the tables being placed on a page that only contains floats. But if you have 100 tables and no text it is hard to make a text page so you make things difficult....